# wikimedia download from google art project

Tags: dump, wikimedia

I'm quite new around. I was looking for a way to download the full resolution images in Wikimedia, from Google art project. Link: [http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Gigapixel_images_from_the_Google_Art_Project](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aGigapixel_images_from_the_Google_Art_Project)

My first thought was downloading the dumps, but how can I know which dump contains the image I am searching? I have little experience handling dumps/coding. I'm really interested in learning how to automatize the process.
Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The dumps include text only and the media tarballs are not sorted by categories.

<del>Just use [catdown](https://toolserver.org/~platonides/catdown/catdown.php), it even ships wget for you if you're unlucky and you're using that user-unfriendly system called Windows.</del> You could try [its replacement](https://tools.wmflabs.org/magnustools/can_i_haz_files.html) (not currently working for me).

You can now **use [Imker](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Imker_%28batch_download%29)**, a Java cross-platform tool.

Comment: Unfortunatly the toolserver is down now. Is this tool replaced on wmflabs?

Comment: @Ainali, added two recent alternatives! :)